# Need to wrap string in 'Single Quotes' on form submission

Tags: javascript, jsp

Hello all this is what I got:

```
 NSN:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="filterCriteria(NSN).values" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="filterCriteria(NSN).fieldName" value="NSN"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="filterCriteria(NSN).operation" value="="/>
```

For database purposes I need to wrap the string of `input value=` in single quotes on form submission.  I guess this can be done in javascript?

Comment: Which input? **Which database purpose**? The database should work fine without any interaction of the user. Otherwise, rewrite your server-side code.

Comment: The guy that is writing the backend has set it up this way

Comment: Shoot that guy down. http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really not the job of JavaScript (which runs - or doesn't - in the browser) to prepare the data for the database query that is performed at server-side.

Never trust any data that comes from the browser. Always use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to bind the parameters of the query and make sure they're correctly escaped and quoted.